# Possible to manipulate background on hover when background is using CSS gradient?

Tags: hover, gradient, css

I have this button which has inline styles.  It is inline because it is user selected so there is no way to link a class to this unfortunately.

So I have this following CSS inline:

```
background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

So my question is which this, how can I apply a hover color where I want to simply inverse the background somehow.  But remember I don't know the colors beforehand so I can't really apply any colors on hover.  But if I simply inverse the background, this it will simulate a hover affect.

In addition, the button can be variable sizes.

Can this be done?

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hLrvA/

I have tried this and it kinda works but not really as it doesn't fill the button.

```
a:hover { background-position:0 -15px !important; }
```

Any insights on how I can pull this off will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to inverse the background color on the hover state would be to exchange the hex values in each background property.

However, you can apply a hover state that uses a gradient based off the colors defined in the gradients for the default state.

[Check it out on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htmled/KPAwc/).

HTML:

```
<a href="#">Button</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1e5799, #7db9e8);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#1e5799, #7db9e8);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#1e5799, #7db9e8);
    background: linear-gradient(#1e5799, #7db9e8);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 );
    background-size:1px 200px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor:pointer; 
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;

    -webkit-transition: background 1s ease-out;
       -moz-transition: background 1s ease-out;
         -o-transition: background 1s ease-out;
            transition: background 1s ease-out;
}

a:hover {
    background-position:100px;
}
```

Comment: No, it does work even if it is not image...And even if I change it to background-image, it is still same effect...but Twitter bootstrap has this and they can make it work for some reason -> http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons

Comment: I understand how to do it if I have to inverse the hex but there is no way as I don't know the hex before hand hence I mentioned, inline styles...If you look at the bootstrap link I posted, you can see they can achieve it without touching the hex....Now I tried following their styles and it works "kinda"...it does change the background position but only partially and not the whole button...so it must be something I am missing...

Comment: Let me post up a fiddle so you can see what i mean

Comment: It looks like they are adjusting the position of the vertical gradient by 15 pixels on hover.

Comment: Ok what if you don't set the width and height and have a line-height of 20px...Can you still make this work?  The reason is user defines the size of the button via the font size not a set width/height...Is it still possible?

Comment: The issue with not defining a fixed height is that the background position defined in the hover state wouldn't be consistent so it wouldn't look the same.

Comment: yeah that is why I said "kinda" works...but I believe twitter bootstrap also does not define width/height...

Comment: You mentioned this "you can apply a hover state that uses a gradient based off the colors".  Could you show me an example of how this would work?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar when trying to change the background-color property on :hover

**HTML**

```
<div class="demo"></div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.demo{
    width: 50px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #388cb6;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #41a2c5 0%, #388cb6 50%, #327cab 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#41a2c5), color-stop(50%,#388cb6), color-stop(100%,#327cab));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #41a2c5 0%,#388cb6 50%,#327cab 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #41a2c5 0%,#388cb6 50%,#327cab 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #41a2c5 0%,#388cb6 50%,#327cab 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #41a2c5 0%,#388cb6 50%,#327cab 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#41a2c5', endColorstr='#327cab',GradientType=0 );

}
.demo:hover{
    background-color: red;
}
```

The above doesn't work, however if you target the background directly and not the more specific background-color it will work:

```css
.demo:hover{
    background: red;
}
```

It appears as though most browsers prefer the single inline background declaration as opposed to individual properties.

Note: I used a pseudo class to illustrate that it is not limited to anchor links.